# Ip address not found for ingress in bare metal installation cent os

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-networking

Ip address not found for ingress in bare metal installation for Cent OS .I created  MetalLB manifest and ConfigMap with ip Pool range. So I Am facing issue with ingress ip address is not found when igress is created[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a76yB.jpg)

Comment: @J Jedidiah , what version of kubernetes do You have and which method was used for installation? Also which network plugin are You using?

Comment: @PiotrMalec Version  Kubernetes v1.16.1   installed using Kube adm  flannel network plugin

Comment: @J Jedidiah, can you paste Your Ingress configuration? Also run and paste output from command `kubectl cluster-info`